# how can I use the shutdown command to hibernate the computer in X hours?

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to hibernate my windows 7 pc in 10 hours after a download is finished. When I execute this:

```
shutdown -h -t 36000
```

All I get is the shutdown help text. Doesn't matter if I'm in admin or normal for the cmd prompt. Is there something I'm missing? I've tried `-t 36000` only with the same results. Same with `/` instead of `-`.

So either a) it isn't working or b) it has a funny way of telling me about it. Do the power management settings interfere with this command?

Update: The `/s` switch shuts the computer down (not hibernate). `/h` is a valid switch. Here's a screenshot of my command:

[image: shutdown cmd screen]

Comment: Have you run "powercfg /hibernate on" yet? And what happens if you run the command with only the /h switch, and no /t switch?

Comment: @goblinbox I tried it with either switch, neither one worked. Do I need to run powercfg to allow shutdown cmd to run the /h switch?

Comment: Hibernate has to be enabled in order to work, yes.

Comment: I swear I've asked the mods to remove the "duplicate" tag from this several times, yet they refuse.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `-h` switch is used to shut down the computer on Linux, not Windows.  The correct command to shut down a Windows computer after 7 hours is:

```
shutdown -s -t 36000
```

Windows will show a dialog box with a countdown until the time the computer will shut down.

But, you want to hibernate, not shutdown, and unfortunately, the `/h` and the `/t` switch don't work together.  As a workaround, you can use the `at` command to schedule `shutdown /h` to run at a certain time.  For example, it is 3:00pm in my time zone at present, so 10 hours later would be 1:00am.  To schedule it to hibernate then, I would run:

```
at 1:00 shutdown /h
```

It uses 24-hour time notation, so if you wanted it to hibernate at 1:00pm, you'd run:

```
at 13:00 shutdown /h
```

Please note, that while you don't need administrator permissions to run the `shutdown` command on default Windows installations, you do need them for the `at` command.

Comment: +1 Shutdown ? will show all switches for the command

Comment: @jcollum:  Sorry about that!  It seems Windows does not support timed hibernation.  Notice if you omit the `/t 36000` switch, the command works.  I'll add a workaround to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I never tested out the /h command by itself because that would've just shut it down immediately. Also, I didn't see anywhere on the man page where it said that they weren't compatible -- how would I have found that?

Comment: The issue with shutting down is that it requires me to go thru and find all the things which might be blocking my computer from shutting down. Hibernating has a lot less friction.

Comment: @jcollum:  Unfortunately, they don't say anything.  Microsoft's online documentation doesn't even make that clear.  I must have tried around 50 different combinations of switches before I gave up and Googled around to see what I might be missing.  As for the stuff blocking shutdown, the `/f` switch should tell `shutdown` to force quit everything on shutdown.

Comment: This is absurd. Timed hibernation **did** work in XP! Windows 7 complicates and breaks things because of the new power modes like hybrid-sleep.

Comment: Not that with Win7 you can't have a timed shutdown that ISN'T forced, also different from XP.

Comment: Under Win 8.1 `at` command refuses to run, stating that it is deprecated and replaced by `schtasks`. Pity.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis I assume this is also true in Windows 10.

Comment: 36000 is after 10 hours, not 7 hours. Should mention that the parameter takes seconds as input.

Comment: `at` column won't run on Windows 11 either. `timeout` from [Joe Internet's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/260120/177334) runs flawlessly : `timeout /t 36000 && shutdown /h`

Answer (score 34):

It doesn't look like the -t option is supported with the -h option for shutdown.

Under Windows 7, you can duplicate what you're trying to do with a .bat script containing the following:

```
timeout /t 36000 /nobreak
shutdown -h
```

It will cause the PC to immediately hibernate once timeout is done counting down.

Comment: You can avoid the batch-file and run it directly too: `timeout /t 36000 /nobreak & shutdown /h`  Of course if you make a batch-file to simplify it, then you should replace the timeout with `%1` so that it is general-purpose.

Comment: One warning though, you can’t abort the shutdown by pressing a key with the `&` version; doing so will immediately shutdown (you are canceling the wait only). With a batch-file, you can press `Ctrl+Break` and CMD will ask if you want to end the batch-file (and thus abort the shutdown) or continue it. So you have choice of behavior. Or, you can write a more batch file with the `choice` and skip `timeout` altogether: `choice /n /t 3600 /d Y /m "Abort hibernate?" & if errorlevel 2 shutdown -h` (however it doesn’t show the time left and is limited to 9999 seconds—for multi-hour, just use `at`).

Comment: @Synetech: It's possible to cancel by closing the window, just tried it.

Comment: Actually the command without a batch file is `timeout /t 36000 /nobreak && shutdown -h` - this will stop if you cancel the timeout. With only one ampersand it would execute the second command then.

Comment: @Sven I think you meant `shutdown /h`. Notice the `/h`, not `-h`.

Answer (score 14):

[**PsShutdown**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) from Sysinternals can hibernate the computer after a specified amount of time.

```
psshutdown -h -t 36000
```

Comment: This is somehow overkill. Two other answers point out a simpler solution. Anyway thank you for the `sysinternals` reference

Comment: @Isaac: How is it overkill? PsShutdown can do more than shutdown can and so is useful to have. I don't think adding extra programs in your path is such a big deal.

Comment: @Isaac How is that overkill? It's simpler than every other solution and just saved my ass! :)

Comment: Unlike built-in shutdown, PsShutdown is unable to display any shutdown notification message on 64-bit Windows OS. It means there is no warning of imminent shutdown/hibernate for the active user.