# Shutdown command hibernate with timer not working

Tags: cmd.exe, shutdown

I'm trying to hibernate my PC after a number of seconds (as I can't see a command to sleep, which would be best).

These work:

```
shutdown /h
shutdown /s /t 5
```

However, this one doesn't:

```
shutdown /h /t 5
```

Which should hibernate after 5 seconds, all I get is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>shutdown /h /t 5
Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /sg | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/soft] [/fw] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
...and so on
```

Can anyone explain why `shutdown /h /t 5` is not working?

Comment: The shutdown command may not be what you want. There are options at https://superuser.com/questions/259791/how-can-i-use-the-shutdown-command-to-hibernate-the-computer-in-x-hours as well as https://superuser.com/questions/83437/hibernate-computer-with-a-timeout-from-command-line-on-windows-7 and probably your best option is combining the hibernate with a delay. The second duplicate suggests `ping -n 20 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1 && shutdown /h /f` and changing the -n 20 to whatever time in seconds you want.

Comment: Fantastic, that works! Thank you Mokubai!